# Beego: How to redirect to other page on session time out

Tags: session, go, session-cookies, session-timeout, beego

i am handling session variable by setting time out using

```
globalSessions, _ = session.NewManager("memory", `{"cookieName":"gosessionid", "enableSetCookie,omitempty": true, "gclifetime":5, "maxLifetime": 5, "secure": false, "sessionIDHashFunc": "sha1", "sessionIDHashKey": "", "cookieLifeTime": 3600, "providerConfig": ""}`)

go globalSessions.GC()

sess, _ := globalSessions.SessionStart(c.Ctx.ResponseWriter, c.Ctx.Request)

defer sess.SessionRelease(c.Ctx.ResponseWriter)

errU := sess.Set("user1", c.Input().Get("userName"))

if errU != nil {
    fmt.Println("error in settng value")
}
```

now how to redirect back to specific page on time out of the current page.
I have this application in beego

Comment: @can any one post suggestions for this... Please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

beego has method `Prepare()` to do this , [see doc](http://beego.me/docs/mvc/controller/controller.md)

**Prepare()**

You can use this function for extension, it will execute before the methods below. You can overwrite it to implement functions such as user validation.

**code**

```
type MainController struct {
    beego.Controller
}

func (c *MainController) Prepare() { 
    if timeOut {
        c.Redirect("login.html", 302)
    }
}

func (c *MainController) Index() {
    c.TplNames = "index.tpl"
}
```